# Why is my Authorize failing when I specify a role which the user has, with JWT token

Tags: authentication, .net-core, jwt, token, authorize

I have implemented a simple JWT authentication system in my code. When using the `[Authorize]` attribute and then analysing the user claim inside the controller code, I can see that the user has the role "Admin" However, if I change the Authorize to `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` I get a 403 returned. Note that I'm testing these methods through Postman.

Token generation:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("Login")]
//[HttpPost("Login/{username}/{password}")]
public IActionResult Login(string username, string password)
{
    var authRepo = new AuthenticationRepository();
    if (authRepo.Login(username, password))
    {
        var ua = new UserAttributes { Email = username, Role = "Admin" };
        var token = GenerateToken(ua);
        return Ok(token);
    }

    return NotFound("User not found");
}

private string GenerateToken(UserAttributes userAttributes)
{
    var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
    var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
    var claims = new[]
    {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userAttributes.Email),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userAttributes.Role)
        };
    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
        _config["Jwt:Audience"],
        claims,
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(_config["Jwt:Expires"])),
        signingCredentials: credentials);


    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}
```

Authorized code:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("TestRole")]
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult AdminEndPoint()
    {
        var currentUser = GetCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null)
            return Ok($"Hi {currentUser.Email} you are an {currentUser.Role}");
        else
            return NotFound();
    }

    private UserAttributes? GetCurrentUser()
    {
        var identity = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (identity != null)
        {
            var userClaims = identity.Claims;
            return new UserAttributes
            {
                Email = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value,
                Role = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)?.Value
            };
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Note that this works, but when I change to `[Authorize(Roles = 'Admin')]` it fails.

For completeness, this is my startup:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options => {
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        RoleClaimType = "role",
        NameClaimType = "name",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
    };
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        OnMessageReceived = msg =>
        {
            var token = msg?.Request.Headers.Authorization.ToString();
            string path = msg?.Request.Path ?? "";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))

            {
                Console.WriteLine("Access token");
                Console.WriteLine($"URL: {path}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Token: {token}\r\n");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Access token");
                Console.WriteLine("URL: " + path);
                Console.WriteLine("Token: No access token provided\r\n");
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Claims from the access token");
            if (ctx?.Principal != null)
            {
                foreach (var claim in ctx.Principal.Claims)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{claim.Type} - {claim.Value}");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnAuthenticationFailed = aut =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exceptoin during authentication");
            Console.WriteLine(aut.Exception);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft and OpenID Connect have different opinion on what the name/role claims should be and because of that ,you need to tell AddJwtBearer what the name of the role and name claim is, using:

```
.AddJwtBearer(opt =>
{
    // ...
    opt.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
    opt.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
    // ...
});
```

For more details, I wrote a blog post about it:

[Debugging JwtBearer Claim Problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/06/02/debugging-jwtbearer-claim-problems-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Thanks, I already have this in my code and it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Also: thanks for the blog post, that's what I used for a lot of my debugging prior to posting this question :) - it got me 99% of the way there!

Comment: Awesome! Glad you liked my blog posts :-), feel free to accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't.

Comment: What happens? I don't see any builder.Services.AddAuthorization(....) in your code? ify you get 403 issues, then that is all about authorization and you have probably not configured it properly . see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: As far as I can tell I don't need a builder.Services.AddAuthorization unless I'm wanting to declare policies. I have app.UseAuthorization in the code. If I simply have the attribute [Authorize] it all works fine, however if I add a role to that attribute I get a 403, even though I can prove the user has that role. This implies to me that the role check is not being done correctly, but I don't know where to look to fix that problem.

Comment: I think builder.Services.AddAuthorization() registers some needed services, but I might be wrong. I would create an endpoint without authorization and look at what claims is actually in the ClaimsPrincipal User object

Comment: Calling AddAuthorization() will end up calling AddAuthorizationCore. This method will add to DI all the core and default implementations of several interfaces that comprise the authorization system in ASP.NET Core. We’ll take a closer look at them later on this post.

https://blog.joaograssi.com/posts/2021/asp-net-core-deep-dive-policy-based-authorization/#addauthorization-and-useauthorization-what-for

Comment: I can confirm that this makes no difference. Note: that it works when the [Authorize] attribute has no roles, so the authorization system must be loaded. Also: I've examined the claim and can confirm that I have the role "Admin".

Comment: ok, are you sure the user.RoleClaimType is set to Role?  Also, be aware of that Role = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)?.Value , that the ClaimTypes.Role is looking for a claim named "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" , see the source here https://source.dot.net/#q=ClaimTypes

Comment: Yep, I can see all this in code and it's all correct. It's just the attribute that won't accept it. I might have to override the attribute handler but that seems annoying as it should work out of the box.

Comment: I would enable Debug log level for the authorization and authentication parts, to let you figure out why it is rejected.